# Создание класса fa fa-times-circle x

Tags: javascript

У элемента `<i>` два класса - *fa-times-circle* и *x* :

```js
let newMessageF = document.createElement('i');
newMessageF.classList.add('fa fa-times-circle x');
```

Как можно создать такой класс на JS ?

Comment: newMessageF.classList.add('fa'); newMessageF.classList.add('fa-times-circle'); newMessageF.classList.add('x');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let newMessageF = document.createElement('i');
newMessageF.className = 'fa fa-times-circle x';
console.log(newMessageF);
```

Или так:

```js
let newMessageF = document.createElement('i');
newMessageF.classList.add('fa', 'fa-times-circle', 'x');
console.log(newMessageF);
```